# How to use OpenGL via SDL2?

Tags: opengles, sdl

I am looking for a "Hello World" type example that makes use of OpenGL-ES2 via SDL2. So far I could gather:

- SDL2 that ships with Raspbian does not support OpenGL-ES2 out of the box
- SDL-2.0.3 manually compiled from source should support OpenGL-ES2 in theory

However even with a manually compiled SDL-2.0.3 I can't get OpenGL-ES2 to work, the displays goes black, so something is working, but even a simple `glClearColor()/glClear()` doesn't have any effect. The same code via EGL or run via OpenGL on a desktop computer however works as expected.

Source code is available at: https://github.com/Grumbel/rpi-opengl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem turned out to not be in the code, but in the library path. A simple `-L/opt/vc/lib/` added to the compile command line fixed it. Without that the compiler would pick:

```
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libGLESv2.so.2
```

While the right one would be (use `ldd` to check):

```
/opt/vc/lib/libGLESv2.so
```

Answer (score 0):

On my RPI the file `/opt/vc/lib/libGLESv2.so` does not exist.
And `libGLESv2.so` gives me a blank screen.

Found that linking to this file works: `/opt/vc/lib/libbrcmGLESv2.so`.

In order to compile a small program with both SDL2 and GLES I needed this command line:

```
g++ -o gltest gltest.cpp -L/opt/vc/lib `sdl2-config --libs` -lbrcmGLESv2
```